# Apache URL rewrite: works with [R] flag, but not without

Tags: apache, redirect, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite a url like this:

`http://www.example.com/~username`

to

`http://www.example.com/index.php?user=username`

The code I have is this:

```
RewriteRule ^/~([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /index.php?user=$1 [NC]
```

If I add an `[R]` flag, it works and redirects to the correct url, but I don't want it to redirect, just to rewrite in the background.  If I remove the `R` flag, I get a 404 error.  This is apache on linux.

Answer (score 0):

Your redirection seems to be working but because its staying on current page, you don't see it. My tests show your thing working as well as the following, but when you add "R" it shows you new page.

> RewriteRule ^/~(username)$    /index.php?user=username$1 [NC,R,L]. # works with R

```
 >  RewriteRule ^/~(username)$  /index.php?user=username$1 [NC,L] # Also works but make sure you have final page working
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a

> redirect in the background

It's that you do not want a **redirect** (HTTP protocol redirection).

What you want is an internal redirection, or alias, or **remapping** in mod-rewrite slug. By removing the `/` part in the rewritten part you may succed in telling mod-rewrite that the thing you are writting is a file system path and not un url path, this way:

```
RewriteRule ^/~([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ index.php?user=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Or better this way, mod-rewrite is enough confusing to stop using short tags:

```
RewriteRule ^/~([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ index.php?user=$1 [last,qsappend,nocase]
```

Now the way mod-rewrite will understand your rule depends on the position of this rule, it it in the Virtualhost general configuration? Is it inside a `Directory` or `Location` directive? Is it inside a .htaccess? a .htaccess in a subdirectory (and what is set in RewriteBase in this case?). So in fact it's always a **mystery**. Removing the '/' may break the rule. Check [the "GET /somepath/pathinfo" examples at the end of official documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), for a human being there is no simple rule (Someone sending me this as a program specification, I would tell him to take a break and ask for some paid help).

But using the **PT|passthrough** flag may succeed, this flag means you really want this rewrite to be handled by filesystem mapping subsystem and not url mapping.

```
RewriteRule ^/~([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ index.php?user=$1 [last,qsappend,nocase,passthrough]
```

Note also that to catch username `^/~([^/]+)/?$` is maybe better than  `^/~([a-zA-Z]+)/?$` (test with username foo42 for example).